# Why No Line Break After Input In Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the code that I'm using for a simple form.  I pretty much copied the entire form from the example on Bootstrap's website, and removed all controls except a text input and the submit button.

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>About You</legend>
        <input class="input-medium" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Get Started</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

For some reason, the submit button doesn't drop to a new line when it comes right after an input.

[image: Demonstration of it not working.]

You'll see, if I just add the checkbox w/ label back from the example, the submit button drops to a new line as expected.

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>About You</legend>
        <input class="input-medium" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
        </label>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Get Started</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

[image: Working when button does not come after text input.]

What am I doing wrong?  I'm using the latest bootstrap CSS and JS (2.3.2), loaded from BootstrapCDN.com.

Comment: I don't really know what that bootstrap is you're working with, but you may want to look at the `display` attribute, and set it to `inline`. (I guess now it is set to `block`, which causes this behavior)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both `<input>` and `<button>` have `display: inline-block`. 
 
`<label>` has `display: block` and forces button to be rendered on the next line.

---

The workaround for displaying button in the next line is simply wrap it in an element with `display: block`, i.e. in a `<div>` element.
Look at this [**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/5395/)

Comment: Throwing it in a `div` worked.  Seems a bit weird though, wish it was documented.  Thanks.

Comment: I created a quick 'helper' class that I use for this now.  Thanks.